# Android AIDL: Service-to-Activity communication

Tags: java, android, aidl

I try to implement a Android AIDL communication strategy.
I have an *Activity* and a *Service*.
My *Activity* can successfully "talk" to my *Service*, but the reverse process does not seem to work.

To summarize, as the *Activity* and the *Service* run in different processes, they cannot share any data throw the  `IBinder`  interface.
So the  `onServiceConnected()`  method receive an AIDL interface instead.
This interface is implemented Service-side and is aimed at being used (called) Activity-side.
I use this *interface* to  `register()`  another AIDL.
This new AIDL is implemented Activity-side and called Service-side through the AIDL interface.
It act like a listener.
Unfortunatly, the method of this new AIDL does not seem to be called.

The *Service* run in its own process thanks to the following line in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".DemoService" android:process=":DemoServiceProcess" />
```

I have 2 AIDL files, one knowing the other.

#### IAidlActivity.aidl

```
package app.test.aidldemo;

interface IAidlActivity {
    void publish(int count);
}
```

#### IAidlService.aidl

```
package app.test.aidldemo;

import app.test.aidldemo.IAidlActivity;
interface IAidlService {
    void startCounter();
    void register(IAidlActivity activity);
}
```

The Service implements  `onBind()`  and run a *handler* in charge of incrementing a counter.

#### DemoService.java

```
package app.test.aidldemo;
import [...]
public class DemoService extends Service
{
    protected IAidlActivity aidlActivity;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return new IAidlService.Stub() {
            @Override
            public void startCounter() {
                DemoService.this.startJob();
            }
            @Override
            public void register(IAidlActivity activity) {
                DemoService.this.aidlActivity = activity;
            }
        };
    }

    public void startJob() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            protected int count = 0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (count < 500) {
                    count++;  // increment counter
                    try {  // then publish it to view
                        DemoService.this.aidlActivity.publish(count);  // interface, implemented activity-side
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {}
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);  // 2sec.
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The *Activity* only consist of a *TextView*.
It start the *bounding* with the *Service* and update the view from time to time.
It is also supposed to update the view when  `publish()`  is called.
But that does not happen.

#### MainActivity.java

```
package app.test.aidldemo;
import [...]
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected TextView view;
    protected ServiceConnection connection;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        view = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(view);
        appendToView("Let's go!");

        connection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                IAidlService aidlService = IAidlService.Stub.asInterface(service);
                appendToView("IAidlService accessed");
                IAidlActivity.Stub aidlActivity = new IAidlActivity.Stub() {
                    @Override
                    public void publish(int count) {
                        appendToView("*** Hey, new count is: " + count + "!! ***");
                    }
                };
                appendToView("IAidlActivity created");
                try {
                    aidlService.register(aidlActivity);
                    aidlService.startCounter();  // interface, implemented service-side
                }
                catch (RemoteException e) { appendToView(e.toString()); }
            }
            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {}
        };

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DemoService.class);
        bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unbindService(connection);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void appendToView(String text) {
        view.append(text + "\n");
    }
}
```

I also try some variations like:

1. run the  `appendToView("*** Hey...`  into  `runOnUiThread()`
2. delay the  `bindService()`  by using another handler + `postDelayed()`

My fallback technique would be to only use *IAidlService* and have a "watcher" Activity-side to constantly check the counter.
But I would rather understand why it is not working, and what is the correct way to use AIDL.

Comment: just for testing call publish() inside register() method

Comment: @pskink Good call. Yes this one works. The call is triggered by the Activity process (through ```register()```), so I am not really surprised. Looks like it fails when the Service process initiate it.

Comment: add some `Log.d` inside `startJob` and trace it

Comment: all right. Took me a while. Looks like ```run()``` was not running in this demo. Now I am creating the Handler using ```new Handler(DemoService.this.getMainLooper())```. So ```run()``` now runs. But the view is still not updated when app is in the foreground. I need to maintain the back button and select again the app to see all the new entries! I tried to use ```View.invalidate()``` to no avail.

Comment: looks like I mastered it in the end. I wrapped the ```view.append()``` (from ```appendToView```) inside a ```view.post(new Runnable() {...})```. I will see if it works well with my initial app and close the *question* if it does.

Comment: well it works. ```view.post(new Runnable() { view.append() })``` do the trick. Thank you @pskink to help me persevere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Summary

2 statements to change.

#### DemoService.java

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(DemoService.this.getMainLooper());
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public void appendToView(String text) {
   view.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           view.append(text + "\n");
       }
    });
}
```